# ImageView with selector in ExpandableListView group changes states on group click

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

I have the following layout for my group in ExpandableListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/color_WHITE"
    android:clickable="false" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_group_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/GROUP_BLUE"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:clickable="false" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_add_group"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_new_item_selector"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view_group_divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/transparent" />
```

ImageView img_add_group has a selector as src, with states for normal, focused and pressed. The problem is it changes states when I click on the entire group row, and not on the image itself (which eventually supposed to act like a button). I tried to change it to Button and to remove the `android:clickable="false"` from LinearLayout and TextView, but then my entire group row stopped functioning and didn't expand, though the button was functioning normally.

How can I fix it?

Comment: do you want the imageview act like button so if just user clicks that , the list expand and if user clickes other section of group the list response nothing , yes?

Comment: No, when the user clicks on the group it should expand, and when he clicks on the ImageView (or a Button, if I'll have to change it) it should open another activity. It currently does it all, but I don't understand why does the ImageView changes state to pressed when I click on the group and not on the image. It should change states only when I click on the ImageView itself.